# Эмуляция оператора goto в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, эмулятор, goto

Во многих языках программирования (например, в С, С++, PHP, Perl, Pascal, Basic) присутствует оператор безусловного перехода — `goto`. В Python его нет, так как (справедливо) считается, что он нарушает логику кода.

У меня возник вопрос — возможно ли эмулировать этот оператор в Питоне? Желательно сделать это так, чтобы команда переводила исполнение непосредственно на указанный номер строки/метку, т. е. чтобы она работала совершенно аналогично своему оригиналу в других языках.

Мои попытки сделать его не увенчались успехом. Пытался использовать `exec`, но запутался вконец.

**P. S.** Вопрос возник в процессе работы над переводом ассемблерного кода на питон. Подчас программы на ассемблере написаны на таком высоком уровне, что разобраться в них физически нереально. Если пытаться переводить, разбивая на какие-то функции, блоки, то существует большой риск нарушить работу программы. Приходится переписывать дословно.

**P. P. S.** Не знаю, нужно ли говорить, что эмулятор должен работать максимально быстро, так как программы ассемблерные и рассчитаны на быстрое выполнение.

Comment: Разбить программу на непрерывные блоки, в конце каждого блока условный или безусловный переход на другой блок. И внешний цикл, который будет запускать каждый блок отдельно, при завершении смотреть, куда идет переход, и переключать выполнение на следующий блок. Без потери производительности в любом случае не получится сделать.

Comment: @insolor, я ж сказал, разбить программу на блоки нереально — программа перестанет работать. Здесь, чтоб понять, нужно знать, как строится программа на ассемблере. Дело в том, что адрес, по которому осуществляется переход может быть изменен, и все разбитие окажется неверным. Так что сделать это нельзя, разве что в "одном блоке одна строчка". Нужен все-таки именно эмулятор — одна краткая команда, без заморочек вроде блоков.

Comment: Тогда ответ на ваш вопрос - никак.

Comment: Проще переписать на чистом Си, ассемблерный код более просто на него транслируется. И работать быстро будет (не представляю, как вы от Python хотите получить "максимально быстро")

Comment: @insolor, я, к сожалению, совсем не знаю Си( Видимо, придется учить. Хорошо, если оставить в стороне быстродействие, неужели нельзя написать эмулятор, пусть даже большой и громоздкий? Может даже для одной конкретной программы, каждую строчку которой как-нибудь занумеровать и поместить в отдельную функцию? Питон же вроде мощный язык?

Comment: Ну парсите код в промежуточный формат (условно, "байткод", но можно просто набор объектов, каждый из которых описывает команду и ее операнды). Создаете для каждого вида команд свою функцию, потом идете по набору объектов-команд, на каждый вызываете нужную функцию, где нужно - выполняете переходы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем то, что вы хотели, но визуально что-то похожее вот сделал с помощью класса питона:

```py
class GoTo():
    ''' goto эмулятор '''
    goto_label = None
    state = False
    running = True

    @staticmethod
    def goto(label_):
        ''' Запоминаем лейбл для перехода '''
        GoTo.goto_label = label_
        GoTo.state = False

    @staticmethod
    def label(label_):
        ''' Проверяем, тот ли лейбл '''
        GoTo.state = GoTo.state or (label_ == GoTo.goto_label)
        return GoTo.state

    def block():
        ''' Начало цикла обработки '''
        GoTo.state = False
        return GoTo.running

    def stop():
        ''' Остановка цикла '''
        GoTo.state = False
        GoTo.running = False

GoTo.goto('2')
while GoTo.block():

    if GoTo.label('1'):
        print('Блок 1')
        print('Завершение')
        GoTo.stop()

    if GoTo.label('2'):
        print('Блок 2')

    if GoTo.label('3'):
        print('Блок 3')
        print('Переход на блок 42')
        GoTo.goto('42')

    if GoTo.label('4'):
        print('Блок 4')

    if GoTo.label('42'):
        print('Блок 42')
        print('Переход на блок 1')
        GoTo.goto('1')
```

Вывод:

```
Блок 2
Блок 3
Переход на блок 42
Блок 42
Переход на блок 1
Блок 1
Завершение
```

То есть как попадается нужный лейбл дальше выполняются все блоки кода после этого лейбла, пока не будет вызвана остановка цикла.

Comment: Супер, спасибо, то что нужно!